# How to map a webview in iPhone app to an Apple Watch app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-watch

I am new to apple watch development. I have a web view in my iOS app. How can I map this web view to my Apple Watch app?

Comment: There is no safari on the Apple Watch.

Comment: @LoVo: It means that we cannot show a web view inside an apple watch app?

Comment: Not on the watch itself but on your iphone check: https://medium.com/@paulcanetti/apple-watch-doesn-t-have-safari-and-you-didn-t-even-notice-a1970ebdb8ed

Comment: You might want to check the possibilities you have with the watch kit: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/WKInterfaceCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a webView on the watch. The recommended thing to do is handoff your URL so they can open it at the iPhone.

Check: http://www.fiveminutewatchkit.com/blog/2015/3/23/how-to-use-handoff-in-your-watchkit-app

Answer (score 0):

On WatchKit you have *WKInterfaceMap* class that allows to display a non-interactive snapshot map (rendered on the device and displayed on the Watch). Also you can add up to 5 annotations, a tap on the map opens Maps application on Watch

Comment: The OP wants to display a WebView, not a MapView